# Определить кодировку

Tags: delphi, кодировка, delphi-7

Может кто-нибудь подсказать как определять кодировки?

```
=D0=D2=CF=D3=D4=CF =D4=C5=CB=D3=D4 --=20 =E1=CC=C5=CB=D3=C1=CE=C4=D2=FF
```

Comment: Если разово - http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/

Если в глобальном смысле, то есть полезная инфографика - http://beta.hstor.org/storage2/61b/e7a/455/61be7a4552a6650bd19b526db63d4779.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще, совсем универсальных способов нет. Но это может помочь[image]

Еще я часто использую декодер:

http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/

Это не единственный такой сайт. Если верить ему, то

```
просто текст --  АлександрЪ???
```

Quoted-printable → KOI8-R